# Python List Index Out of Range When Passing to Child Function

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```py
@task()
def record_racedata(teamname, cron_min):
    def wrapper(teamname):
        team = nitrotype.Team(teamname)    # error here (nitrotype is a valid object)
        
        for members in team.data["members"]:
            # more things
    
    schedule = crontab(minute=cron_min)
    task_name = 'record_racedata_%s_%s' % (int(time.time()), teamname)
    periodic_task(schedule, name=task_name)(wrapper(teamname))

record_racedata('team1', '*/1')
```

This throws the following error at the marked line:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I decided to get rid of the `teamname` argument into the following code *and this worked*:

```py
@task()
def record_racedata(teamname, cron_min):  # did not use "teamname" variable
    def wrapper():
        team = nitrotype.Team("team1") 
        
        for members in team.data["members"]:
            # more things
    
    schedule = crontab(minute=cron_min)
    task_name = 'record_racedata_%s_%s' % (int(time.time()), teamname)
    periodic_task(schedule, name=task_name)(wrapper)

record_racedata('team1', '*/1')
```

Which implies that the library I was using was working, but the error occurred because I somehow passed the argument `teamname` down incorrectly. Can anybody please help?

This is the scheduler that I was trying to use: [link](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#dynamic-periodic-tasks)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the code for `nitrotype.Team`? The error is probably happening somewhere in there.

Comment: [Imgur gallery](https://imgur.com/a/4A86WAB). The first image (marked with the red arrow) is the exact line where the error occurred, but the formatted JSON (second image) implies that the returned data is proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're more or less defining a closure here, and in the first version, your function needs an argument. I suspect that just removing the argument for the inner function should make it work since the `teamname` will be essentially "locked in" afterwards as in my example below:

```
In [27]: def closure(s):
    ...:     def print_s():
    ...:         print(s)
    ...:         return
    ...:     return print_s

In [28]: h = closure('hello world'); b = closure('goodbye')

In [29]: h(); b()
hello world
goodbye
```

So you'll want something like:

```
@task()
def record_racedata(teamname, cron_min):
    def wrapper():
        team = nitrotype.Team(teamname)
        ...
```